# BSOD BUGCODE_USB_DRIVER - dump file included

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, bsod, dump

I've been getting 2 or 3 BSOD every day and it's always the same error. I have been searching for a fix, but haven't had any luck. Any help is appreciated.

Laptop - Dell 1764 (Windows 7 64 bit)

Here's the dump file: http://www.mediafire.com/?9rfyxwjby1zlyjo

Please let me know if there is more information needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem. The webcam on the laptop was causing the problem. I unhooked it a few weeks ago and have had no problems since. I just wanted to leave this in case someone else has this problem.